# Does the business logic for deserializing a JsonPayload have to match?

Tags: json, vb.net

I am currently attempting to deserialize a Json Payload that has been fired from a webhook URL on an MVC application, but I do not know if the business logic provided has to match exactly to prevent any null values.

Basically the Json Payload contains way to much useless information that I do not what to display.  This is a brief preview of what the Payload looks like:

```
"webhookEvent":"jira:issue_updated",
"user":{
"self":"http://gtlserver1:8080/rest/api/2/user?username=codonoghue",
"name":"codonoghue",
"issue":{
"id":"41948",
"self":"http://gtlserver1:8080/rest/api/2/issue/41948",
"key":"OP-155",
"fields":{
"summary":"Test cc recipient",
"progress":{
"progress":0,
"total":0}, ....
```

I only want to display information about the issue and the other information is just white noise to me and don't want to use it.  Now do I have to create classes only for the issue details etc like this:

```
Public Class jiraIssue
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property key As String
    Public Property fields As jiraFields
End Class
```

Or do I have to make sure to provide sufficient business logic about the **User** class just to make sure that it will be received correctly?  I also know that using **Json2csharp.com** the classes that can be made are **user**, **issue**, **fields**, **progress** as well as the overall **RootObject**, so I also want to know is do these classes need to contain the exact same matching variables as the JsonPayload, e.g. I don't want progress to have the variable total.

When using Json2csharp that in every class they contain an ID variable with the property as string and I would like to know if this is needed in the classes to be able to display the information or can I not use it as it is also irrelevant.

The main thing that I want to deserialize is the **RootObject**, which contains a **webhookEvent (string)** an **issue** (which links to issue class, which links to fields class which links to all relevant information), comment which links to a comment class.  I want to deserialize this so would this be correct?

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property webhookEvent As String
    Public Property issue As Issue
    Public Property comment As Comment2
    Public Property timestamp As Long
End Class

Public Class Issue
    Public Property key As String
    Public Property fields As Fields
End Class

Public Class Fields
    Public Property issueType as IssueType
    Public Property summary As String
    Public Property summary As String
End Class



Dim Issue As RootObject = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of RootObject)(json)

For Each item As var In Issue.issue
    Console.WriteLine("WebhookEvent: {0}, issue: {1}", item.WebhookEvent, item.issue)
Next
```

**Update**

It seems that the problems that I was having was due to the JsonPayload itself, the business logic did not affect.  There were issues with the incompatible characters, some fields were null and could not be and a few others as well.

Comment: Why do you use `JSONP` term? How this applies to JIRA web hooks?

Comment: @AleksandrIvanov So far I have created an application that sends an email to JIRA to submit an issue once this is done the webhook will fire to my application a JSON payload which is currently in requestb.in which is were I am getting this information, I need to use the correct business logic so that l can consume this correctly and display certain pieces of the information but not everything

Comment: It's normal to have only data that you need in your models.

Comment: I need to data from the JsonPayload I just created the model classes so that I could display the information sent from the Payload

Comment: What do you mean by _Payload_?

Comment: the Json Payload is just the Json sent by the webhook {"webhookEvent":"jira:issue_updated","user":} etc I am trying to deserialize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have correctly got my Json payload correctly read in and the Json Payload information does not have to correctly match up with the classes that you create.  You only have to create classes and variables for the information that you need from the Json Payload.  For example if you did not want the information on comments do not create a comment class.

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property webhookEvent As String
    Public Property issue As Issue
    ' Public Property comment As Comment2   
    ' comment out the comment class because it is not needed
    Public Property timestamp As Long
End Class
```